# Taking the sum of variables in python

Tags: python, variables

So I have the following code, for some reason the two variables "large" and "small" doesn't seem to add up and I don't know why. Please help me.

```
n = int(input("number:" ))

x = map(int, str(n))
x = [int(x) for x in tal]

x.sort(reverse=True)
large = "".join(map(str, x))

x.sort()
small = "".join(map(str, x))

int(large)
int(small)

large + small=y

print(y)
```

Comment: I think it should be `y = large + small`? What is `tal` and why your using `int(str(int(n)))`

Comment: what error do you get there are many  error in your program

Comment: What is the variable `tal` you used in the list comprehension ?

Comment: why you write this  
`int(large)
int(small)` ? what is the point?

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
int(large)
int(small)

large + small=y
```

to

```
large = int(large)
small = int(small)

y = large + small
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be: `y = large + small`

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
y = large + small
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
y = large+small
```

What is tal, btw?